# How can I map and Object with Arrays as values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given the following array of objects with dates in UTC:

```
const Arr = [
{
"name": "Person 1",
"date": "2021-02-28T14:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"name": "Person 2",
"date": "2021-02-28T19:15:00.000+0000"
},
{
"name": "Person 3",
"date": "2021-04-04T18:30:00.000+0000"
},
{
"name": "Person 4",
"date": "2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"name": "Person 5",
"date": "2021-05-12T18:45:00.000+0000"
},
{
"name": "Person 6",
"date": "2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000"
},
{
"name": "Person 7",
"date": "2021-05-23T15:00:00.000+0000"
}
];
```

I grouped the items by date using `reduce` as described in the below code:

```
const eventDate = {};
Arr.reduce((groupByDate, event) => {
 const date = event.date.split('T')[0];

 if (!groupByDate[date]) {
  groupByDate[date] = [];
 }

 groupByDate[date].push(event);
 return groupByDate;
}, {});
```

Getting an object grouped by date (as key) and an array of objects (as values):

```
{
'2021-02-28': [
  { name: 'Person 1', date: '2021-02-28T14:00:00.000+0000' },
  { name: 'Person 2', date: '2021-02-28T19:15:00.000+0000' }
],
'2021-04-04': [ { name: 'Person 3', date: '2021-04-04T18:30:00.000+0000' } ],
'2021-05-11': [
  { name: 'Person 4', date: '2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000' },
  { name: 'Person 6', date: '2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000' }
],
'2021-05-12': [ { name: 'Person 5', date: '2021-05-12T18:45:00.000+0000' } ],
'2021-05-23': [ { name: 'Person 7', date: '2021-05-23T15:00:00.000+0000' } ]
}
```

So my doubt here is how can I loop through that new object in order to get something like this?
(date in UTC will be formatted and get only the time)

---

```
2021-02-28:
name: Person 1 time: 14:00
name: Person 2 time: 19:15

2021-04-04:
name: Person 3 time: 18:30

2021-05-11:
name: Person 4 time: 19:00
name: Person 6 time: 19:00

2021-05-12:
name: Person 5 time: 18:45

2021-05-23:
name: Person 7 time: 15:00
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the output as `console.log` or as specific data structure?

Comment: Hi @GuerricP, the data structure if is not inconvenient, please.

Comment: Just mutate the date in the reduce instead of pushing the existing event. `groupByDate[date].push({name: event.name, time: event.date.substr(11, 5)});`

Comment: As @GuerricP said what data structure? object? array? string?

Comment: Thanks, @pilchard that format the time but I'm getting problems mapping that Object. Not sure how to loop through that values (Array)

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean by 'map' it. What is your expected output? If it's just a console.log then Aaron Beall's answer works below.

Comment: so... you're asking how to convert an object of arrays into html/text?

Comment: Hi @KevinB and plichard with just console.log() is fine. As you mention Aaron Beall answer works perfectly!. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()` on the top level object to loop over it (for example using `forEach()` or any other looping method):

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, items]) => {
  console.log(key);
  items.forEach(item => {
    console.log("name:", item.name, "date:", item.date)
  })
})
```

[Playround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAsAKAOQBMADAQIwC0J5BAHHgFwwDauMmMYCAtgKaN4AFHgCcI4GKTwAaeEj4xCJClVoAVUgBZ6RItqIA6HUQDURonhgBfKa3ade-IaPEFpsqPMVlKBajXUAnPSkAKx6hjqmRhaWuAC6NvjE3kQalBoMzHbcnk5iYDAAzG6IHvzJymmp6jT0hbo6ESZmMTAJuF7KIeSkkowsOGwYHDmOIvkwGTKlnhWU3b2BeuFGUToxiUMjDgp54gBsJXLlSvM9pEs6K5EtVvGJnWekrv3ZO4Lj4iFHZQpzRAsCDV6Bowo1VrdLG0Hv9ugRiq9hvZcp8CgB2H6zU4A6iFdRghoGCHRKxtXCxHC4ADyACMAFY8YBQfQ8MBQYQASx4EAAFKUEABKfQAMxAwgAoghgAALHk8pgAax4AE8ZByPFwIHEBWgAHyYWygSAgAA2PH0JpAAHMeUrlQKANy2dU8TUisWSmU8l1cPUGwZsGBGsRmi3WnkAImR9Ajao1%20mRMgjMxjcdd%20hmAtslizOBzQA)

Comment: That solution was exactly what I need it. Thank you very much, @Aaron Beall !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```js
const obj = {
  '2021-02-28': [
    { name: 'Person 1', date: '2021-02-28T14:00:00.000+0000' },
    { name: 'Person 2', date: '2021-02-28T19:15:00.000+0000' }
  ],
  '2021-04-04': [{ name: 'Person 3', date: '2021-04-04T18:30:00.000+0000' }],
  '2021-05-11': [
    { name: 'Person 4', date: '2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000' },
    { name: 'Person 6', date: '2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000' }
  ],
  '2021-05-12': [{ name: 'Person 5', date: '2021-05-12T18:45:00.000+0000' }],
  '2021-05-23': [{ name: 'Person 7', date: '2021-05-23T15:00:00.000+0000' }]
}

const newObj = {}
const newSubObj = {}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  newObj[key] = []
  newSubObj[key] = []

  for (const item of value) {
    const date = new Date(item.date)
    const subDate = item.date.substr(11, 5)

    const hours = date.getUTCHours()
    const minutes = date.getUTCMinutes()

    newObj[key].push({ name: item.name, time: `${hours}:${minutes}` })
    newSubObj[key].push({ name: item.name, time: subDate })
  }
}

console.log(newObj, newSubObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to `console.log()` the result this is how I will do it:

```js
const obj = {
    '2021-02-28': [
      { name: 'Person 1', date: '2021-02-28T08:00:00.000+0000' },
      { name: 'Person 2', date: '2021-02-28T19:15:00.000+0000' }
    ],
    '2021-04-04': [ { name: 'Person 3', date: '2021-04-04T18:30:00.000+0000' } ],
    '2021-05-11': [
      { name: 'Person 4', date: '2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000' },
      { name: 'Person 6', date: '2021-05-11T19:00:00.000+0000' }
    ],
    '2021-05-12': [ { name: 'Person 5', date: '2021-05-12T18:45:00.000+0000' } ],
    '2021-05-23': [ { name: 'Person 7', date: '2021-05-23T15:00:00.000+0000' } ]
}

const printObj = (obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        console.log(`${key}:`);
        obj[key].forEach(val => {
            const currentDate = new Date(val.date);
            const currentDateHours = (currentDate.getUTCHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentDate.getUTCHours();
            const currentDateMinutes = (currentDate.getUTCMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentDate.getUTCMinutes();
            console.log(`name: ${val.name} time: ${currentDateHours}:${currentDateMinutes}`);
        })
    });
}

printObj(obj);
```

**Note**: `getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()` will not show two digit number in case of a leading `0`, I took it into consideration.